# Get tag content from a lot of urls

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp-classic

I have a situation here: in CSV file have a lot of URL's - more than 3000 in that format:

www.site1.com/product1

www.site1.com/product2

www.site1.com/product3

....

www.site1.com/product3001

from all page i must read specific tag - `<div id="cat">category1</div>`

I've try to solve this on server side, but that require a lot of server resources and cause Time Out err. Then i wonder - is there a way that i can do that with some kind of java script or jQuery? In that case, browser will take the traffic. Of course - this will take some time... but better than get TimeOut from server.

Comment: You can't send cross-domain AJAX requests unless all those foreign servers send CORS headers. I would advise to not process all URIs at once.

Comment: iframe source requests would handle that problem .... but the better question is do you need to do this every time someone requests the page, or on a schedule? a ton of different options for this screen scrape.... and does the content of div#cat need to be associated with the URI? with the Product1 part? Kept around? Discarded? 3001 requests is a lot of load to put on site1.com if it's not your own system....

Comment: Believe me it will be more faster in server side. or else you have to make 3000 ajax request to process all pages. Plus You must also take care of cross domain problems.
If you are making one or few ajax at a time than only do on browser.

Comment: @Tetsujin no Oni - this will be a sheduled task, performed 1 time in month.
I agree for server side, but that 2/3-th of time is in load source waiting :( I have a permission from site1.com owners to do that, but they can't give me some sort of limited response. So, for good ot worse, i must crawl all URL's and do the job on hard way :(

Comment: If you have reasonable control of the server on which this scheduled task will run, it'd be way simpler with HtmlAgilityPack and .Net components in an .exe rather than using ASP3.

Comment: @Tetsujin no Oni - this is good. I have full control on server and i'll try this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible with some ajax calls and then looking for that particular element (id="cat"). But i guess the sites must be on the same server/domain for this to work.

Another method i would try is to create an iframe and on a loop load the page and wait for the onload method of the iframe, after it's loaded i would look for that particular element and get its content... This is somewhat more likely to work but it will be painfully slow...

```
var urls = [url1, url2, url3...]; //get all the urls from your file
var urlsLength = urls.length; //get the number of urls to loop for
var iFrame = document.createElement("iframe"); //create an iframe
var iframeContainer = document.getElementById("iframeContainer"); //iframeContainer must exists on your page, you can even hide it with display="none"
var iFrameBody; //variable to hold the iframe body
iframeContainer.appendChild( iFrame ); //add the iframe to its container
for( var i = 0; i<urlsLength; ++i ){ //loop for all the urls
    iFrame.src = urls[i]; //browse the designated url
    iFrame.onload = function(){ //when it loads, then do your work
        iFrameBody = iFrame.contentDocument || iFrame.contentWindow.document; //get the body of the iFrame
        doSomething( iFrameBody.getElementById("ELEMENT ID TO LOOK FOR") ); //send the element to your functions
    }
}

//this function will receive the element from inside the iframe, you can do whatever you need to 
function doSomething(element){
 var elementHTML = element.innerHTML;
 console.log( element );
}
```

-EDIT-

This method is way too slow, as mentioned above in the comments, doing this server side is (IMHO) the best approach, but at least you have alternatives, i would stay away from AJAX requests to do something like this on massive urls ( 30+ ) and stick to iframes, but still believe that server side is the GO GO. Cheers.

Comment: I would like to thanks to all. In conclusion - server side or browser (client) side - there is no fast way that I can get source of that big QTY of url's, and it's all lead to write some fine CRON job task to perform that takes nice and quietly at midnight. IFRAME technique is good for that I can outsource some of check's on outside machine.

Comment: You're welcome, iframe, ajax and any other way you try will be slow since it needs to wait for the url to fully load to access to the element you're targeting... For the looks of it, you're trying to get product(s) information, isn't it better to ask for a csv file from that site owner that (s)he can get from a simple DB query?

Comment: yeah - this will be perfect - but suddenly - impossible.

Comment: Alrighty, if anything else is needed you know where to find me pal. Cheers.